# Expose function with function declaration

Tags: javascript

Right now I have the following set up:

```
var foo = 'bar';
function alertFoo() {
    alert(foo);
};
```

If I want to scope `foo` so that it is not global, I can do it with the following function expression:

```
var alertFoo = (function() {
    var foo = 'bar';
    return function() {
        alert(foo);
    }
)();
```

Is there a way to convert this function expression to a function declaration similar to the first code example?

Comment: Which function expression are you talking about - the one inside, with just the `alert()` call, or the one outside?

Comment: The one on the outside, I'd like `alertFoo` to be hoisted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

Re your comment:

> The one on the outside, I'd like alertFoo to hoisted

Well, you *can* do this:

```
function alertFoo() {
    var foo = 'bar';

    doTheAlert();

    function doTheAlert() {
        alert(foo);
    }
}
```

...but I can't imagine that really suits your needs. Other than that, no, you can't get it hoisted.

**Original answer**:

Yes, you can declare the function within the function expression, like this:

```
var alertFoo = (function() {
    var foo = 'bar';

    return alertFoo;

    function alertFoo() {
        alert(foo);
    }
}();
```

Or you can declare the scoping function and *then* call it, but then you create another symbol in the current scope:

```
function scoping() {
    var foo = 'bar';

    return alertFoo;

    function alertFoo() {
        alert(foo);
    }
)
var alertFoo = scoping();
```

Comment: I think he's actually wondering if there's a way to get rid of `var alertFoo =`.

Comment: Wouldn't `return function alertFoo() { alert(foo): }` be enough for the first example?

Comment: Yep, I'd like to know if its possible to have `alertFoo` as a function declaration and not assigned via expression

Comment: @user2066880: *"...as a function declaration and not an object..."* It's not an object (other than that all JavaScript functions are objects) in any of your examples.

Comment: Sorry, rather I meant that `alertFoo` is a function declaration as opposed to a function expression so that it is hoisted up.

Comment: Saw your updated answer, since I'd like to initialize the `foo` property only once and used for all `alertFoo()` calls, I don't think I can use a function declaration. Thanks.

Comment: @user2066880: Right, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `alertFoo` in such a way that it replaces itself with a closure the first time it is called:

```
function alertFoo() {
    var foo = 'bar';
    alertFoo = function() {
        alert(foo);
    };
    alertFoo();
}
```

That gives you the best of both worlds: a function declaration that hoists and a closure.

Demo that this works:

```
function foo() {
    var counter = 0;
    foo = function() { console.log(counter++); };
    foo();
}
```

With output:

> > foo()
>   0
>   > foo()
>   1
>   > foo()
>   2

One downside to this approach is that `alertFoo` becomes a different object on the first call. This might well cause problems if references to `alertFoo` were created before its first execution.

Answer (score -2):

Research closures.

```
(function( global ) {
  var foo = 'bar';
  function alertFoo() {
    alert(foo);
  };
})( window );
```

Comment: What is the `global` parameter for?

Comment: And how should `alertFoo` be accessed from outside. Currently it is _trapped_ inside of the closure.

Comment: Research difference between function expression and declaration ;)